# why the output is incorrect in my Shell string?

Tags: linux, shell, grep

The script is as below:

```
a=`sed '/^project_folder=/!d;s/.*=//' conf.ini | tr -d '\r'`
b=`sed '/^version.versionLicense=/!d;s/.*=//' conf.properties`

path=${a}/${b}/env/123456/bin
echo $path
```

the content of conf.ini is `project_folder=/data/AUTO-PUBLISH/iPEMS_01`

the content of conf.properties is `version.versionLicense=3.1.0.3`

the output is `/env/123456/binISH/iPEMS_01/3.1.0.3`

my expected output is `/data/AUTO-PUBLISH/iPEMS_01/3.1.0.3/env/123456/bin`

Why this happened?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: `conf.properties` will have `\r`, which will part of `$path` now.

Comment: @Allan my expected output is /data/AUTO-PUBLISH/iPEMS_01/3.1.0.3//env/123456/bin

Comment: @WalterA  Thanks, you're right

Comment: @AlexBruce: Have you checked my answer? I would really recommend to go for a `grep` approach than using `sed` since you are manipulating the input string in `sed` by deleting lines that you d not need etc what will cost you a lot of CPU cycles

Comment: @Allan It's correct as well.

Comment: If you really want to use `sed` then at least change your command to a better `sed` command, you do not need to delete rows, use: 
`sed '/^project_folder=/s/.*=//'` and `sed '/^version\.versionLicense=/s/.*=//'` This will save you some cpu cycles, save you some bytes in your script and save you some input with your keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `sed` for what you are doing grep would be more than enough as you can see hereunder:

```
$ more conf.properties conf.ini 
::::::::::::::
conf.properties
::::::::::::::
version.versionLicense=3.1.0.3
::::::::::::::
conf.ini
::::::::::::::


$ grep -oP '(?<=^project_folder=).*' conf.ini | tr -d '\r'
/data/AUTO-PUBLISH/iPEMS_01

$ grep -oP '(?<=version\.versionLicense=).*' conf.properties | tr -d '\r' 
3.1.0.3
```

Your script becomes:

```
a=$(grep -oP '(?<=^project_folder=).*' conf.ini | tr -d '\r')                                                                                
b=$(grep -oP '(?<=version\.versionLicense=).*' conf.properties | tr -d '\r')
path=${a}/{$b}/env/123456/bin
echo $path
```

And the output is:

```
/data/AUTO-PUBLISH/iPEMS_01/{3.1.0.3}/env/123456/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

conf.properties will have \r, which will part of $path now.